# What is the maximum columns limit or characters limit for BCP out export?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008, bcp

I am trying to import data from a file using BCP.

I have 240 columns in the file but it is accepting 178 columns only. Is there a column limit for BCP?

I am using table Export.

```
BCP Table out \\Sharepath\folder -Usa -T -c -t "|" -Server
```

Comment: Hi Nani. Table imports are using `BCP in` mode, not `BCP out` as you have in the command sample at the bottom. Also, for import commands it is recommended to use a format file.

Comment: Hi , I am exporting my table to flat file , i am not getting complete data ,

Comment: i have more then 240 columns in my table , can you please help me

Comment: Oh, then at the bottom, you meant to say "I am using table **export**."?

Comment: i am exporting data to flat file , i am not getting whole columns ?

Comment: There is no limit to the number of columns in BCP. The maximum is the maximum allowed for a table in SQL Server (which is more than 240). Are you absolutely sure you are only seeing 178 columns?

Comment: I have more then 240 columns in a table , when i generate output i am not getting whole columns , is there any characters limit for a line in BCP Out , because i have verified in one server it is showing 178 columns , for some other table it is showing 154 columns in output file , i thick there is a characters limit for line , ????

Comment: Do you have character fields that can have newline symbols in them?

Comment: Let me explain what is exact issue , there is no character fields , i am getting output like below , example columns : Name | Address | Salary |........| mob

Comment: it is limiting up to some characters only , it has to write  Name | Address | Salary |........| mobile | ..and so on ,up to my last column

Comment: Nani, it is not quite clear what mean when you say "not getting whole columns". Are you saying: 1 you are not getting all the fields in the file that you have in your table? Meaning you have 240 columns in the table and you are only getting 178 pipe-delimiters in your file? or 2 you are getting truncated data for some of your 240 columns. Meaning all columns are there (you have 238 pipes delimiting fields in your file) but some of them are truncated to lengths shorter than you anticipated? or possibly 3.. both are happening?

Comment: Im sure this can be resolved, but it's not clear what you are seeing that is an issue.

Comment: As TT stated already, there is no limit inherent to BCP. Any limit you may encounter will be a product of a limitation of the SQL Server the bcp utility is connecting with. But as you've pointed out, you have the 240 columns in the data already as you are exporting data out... so we can rule out there being any limitation involved.